# darknet make error collector2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, ld, darknet

darknet

My application is to record sound via microphone, to preprocess like fft, and to classify voice activities. I composed own code that deals with recording,converting into *.wav,and doing learning and predicting in the name of sound.c. At this time, I do not need image processing.
Anyway, followings are what I get during make.

```
@-desktop:~/darknet_tmp$ make
PATH:=/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/lib64
g++ -std=c++11 -std=c++11 -Iinclude/ -I3rdparty/stb/include -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -DCUDNN -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -DCUDNN -I/usr/local/cudnn/include -fPIC obj/sound.o obj/http_stream.o obj/gemm.o obj/utils.o obj/dark_cuda.o obj/convolutional_layer.o obj/list.o obj/image.o obj/activations.o obj/im2col.o obj/col2im.o obj/blas.o obj/crop_layer.o obj/dropout_layer.o obj/maxpool_layer.o obj/softmax_layer.o obj/data.o obj/matrix.o obj/network.o obj/connected_layer.o obj/cost_layer.o obj/parser.o obj/option_list.o obj/darknet.o obj/detection_layer.o obj/captcha.o obj/route_layer.o obj/writing.o obj/box.o obj/nightmare.o obj/normalization_layer.o obj/avgpool_layer.o obj/coco.o obj/dice.o obj/yolo.o obj/detector.o obj/layer.o obj/compare.o obj/classifier.o obj/local_layer.o obj/swag.o obj/shortcut_layer.o obj/activation_layer.o obj/rnn_layer.o obj/gru_layer.o obj/rnn.o obj/rnn_vid.o obj/crnn_layer.o obj/demo.o obj/tag.o obj/cifar.o obj/go.o obj/batchnorm_layer.o obj/art.o obj/region_layer.o obj/reorg_layer.o obj/reorg_old_layer.o obj/super.o obj/voxel.o obj/tree.o obj/yolo_layer.o obj/gaussian_yolo_layer.o obj/upsample_layer.o obj/lstm_layer.o obj/conv_lstm_layer.o obj/scale_channels_layer.o obj/sam_layer.o obj/convolutional_kernels.o obj/activation_kernels.o obj/im2col_kernels.o obj/col2im_kernels.o obj/blas_kernels.o obj/crop_layer_kernels.o obj/dropout_layer_kernels.o obj/maxpool_layer_kernels.o obj/network_kernels.o obj/avgpool_layer_kernels.o -o darknet -lm -pthread -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -L/usr/local/cudnn/lib64 -lcudnn -lstdc++
obj/darknet.o: In function `main':
darknet.c:(.text.startup+0xae): undefined reference to `show_opencv_info'
obj/network_kernels.o: In function `backward_network_gpu':
tmpxft_00001197_00000000-6_network_kernels.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xc90): undefined reference to `resize_window_cv'
obj/network_kernels.o: In function `train_network_datum_gpu':
tmpxft_00001197_00000000-6_network_kernels.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x163a): undefined reference to `resize_window_cv'
tmpxft_00001197_00000000-6_network_kernels.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1644): undefined reference to `wait_key_cv'
obj/data.o: In function `load_data_detection':
data.c:(.text+0x4dba): undefined reference to `wait_until_press_key_cv'
obj/data.o: In function `load_data_augment':
data.c:(.text+0x5ad2): undefined reference to `wait_until_press_key_cv'
obj/network.o: In function `train_network_waitkey':
network.c:(.text+0x13db): undefined reference to `wait_key_cv'
obj/writing.o: In function `test_writing':
writing.c:(.text+0x9ae): undefined reference to `wait_until_press_key_cv'
writing.c:(.text+0x9b5): undefined reference to `destroy_all_windows_cv'
obj/coco.o: In function `test_coco':
coco.c:(.text+0x1ac0): undefined reference to `wait_until_press_key_cv'
coco.c:(.text+0x1ac7): undefined reference to `destroy_all_windows_cv'
obj/yolo.o: In function `test_yolo':
yolo.c:(.text+0x1a40): undefined reference to `wait_until_press_key_cv'
yolo.c:(.text+0x1a47): undefined reference to `destroy_all_windows_cv'
obj/detector.o: In function `test_detector':
detector.c:(.text+0x8a0b): undefined reference to `wait_until_press_key_cv'
detector.c:(.text+0x8a12): undefined reference to `destroy_all_windows_cv'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:173: recipe for target 'darknet' failed
make: *** [darknet] Error 1
```

I need your help and advice.

```
Makefile

GPU=1
CUDNN=1
CUDNN_HALF=0
OPENCV=0
AVX=0
OPENMP=0
LIBSO=1
ZED_CAMERA=0
ZED_CAMERA_v2_8=0
export PATH:=${PATH}:/usr/local/cuda/bin
export PATH:=${PATH}:/usr/local/cuda/lib64
$(info PATH:=${PATH})

# set GPU=1 and CUDNN=1 to speedup on GPU
# set CUDNN_HALF=1 to further speedup 3 x times (Mixed-precision on Tensor Cores) GPU: Volta, Xavier, Turing and higher
# set AVX=1 and OPENMP=1 to speedup on CPU (if error occurs then set AVX=0)
# set ZED_CAMERA=1 to enable ZED SDK 3.0 and above
# set ZED_CAMERA_v2_8=1 to enable ZED SDK 2.X

USE_CPP=0
DEBUG=0

#ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
#      -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
#      -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] \
#      -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] \
#     -gencode arch=compute_61,code=[sm_61,compute_61]
ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61


OS := $(shell uname)

# Tesla A100 (GA100), DGX-A100, RTX 3080
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_80,code=[sm_80,compute_80]

# Tesla V100
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_70,code=[sm_70,compute_70]

# GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, RTX 2080, RTX 2070, Quadro RTX 8000, Quadro RTX 6000, Quadro RTX 5000, Tesla T4, XNOR Tensor Cores
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_75,code=[sm_75,compute_75]

# Jetson XAVIER
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_72,code=[sm_72,compute_72]

# GTX 1080, GTX 1070, GTX 1060, GTX 1050, GTX 1030, Titan Xp, Tesla P40, Tesla P4
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61

# GP100/Tesla P100 - DGX-1
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60

# For Jetson TX1, Tegra X1, DRIVE CX, DRIVE PX - uncomment:
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_53,code=[sm_53,compute_53]

# For Jetson Tx2 or Drive-PX2 uncomment:
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_62,code=[sm_62,compute_62]


VPATH=./src/
EXEC=darknet
OBJDIR=./obj/

ifeq ($(LIBSO), 1)
LIBNAMESO=libdarknet.so
APPNAMESO=uselib
endif

ifeq ($(USE_CPP), 1)
CC=g++
else
CC=gcc
endif

CPP=g++ -std=c++11
NVCC=nvcc
OPTS=-Ofast
LDFLAGS= -lm -pthread
COMMON= -Iinclude/ -I3rdparty/stb/include
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wfatal-errors -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fPIC

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
#OPTS= -O0 -g
#OPTS= -Og -g
COMMON+= -DDEBUG
CFLAGS+= -DDEBUG
else
ifeq ($(AVX), 1)
CFLAGS+= -ffp-contract=fast -mavx -mavx2 -msse3 -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -msse4a
endif
endif

CFLAGS+=$(OPTS)

ifneq (,$(findstring MSYS_NT,$(OS)))
LDFLAGS+=-lws2_32
endif

ifeq ($(OPENCV), 1)
COMMON+= -DOPENCV
CFLAGS+= -DOPENCV
LDFLAGS+= `pkg-config --libs opencv4 2> /dev/null || pkg-config --libs opencv`
COMMON+= `pkg-config --cflags opencv4 2> /dev/null || pkg-config --cflags opencv`
endif

ifeq ($(OPENMP), 1)
    ifeq ($(OS),Darwin) #MAC
        CFLAGS+= -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp
    else
        CFLAGS+= -fopenmp
    endif
LDFLAGS+= -lgomp
endif

ifeq ($(GPU), 1)
COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/
CFLAGS+= -DGPU
ifeq ($(OS),Darwin) #MAC
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
else
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
endif
endif

ifeq ($(CUDNN), 1)
COMMON+= -DCUDNN
ifeq ($(OS),Darwin) #MAC
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN -I/usr/local/cuda/include
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcudnn
else
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN -I/usr/local/cudnn/include
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cudnn/lib64 -lcudnn
endif
endif

ifeq ($(CUDNN_HALF), 1)
COMMON+= -DCUDNN_HALF
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN_HALF
ARCH+= -gencode arch=compute_70,code=[sm_70,compute_70]
endif

ifeq ($(ZED_CAMERA), 1)
CFLAGS+= -DZED_STEREO -I/usr/local/zed/include
ifeq ($(ZED_CAMERA_v2_8), 1)
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/zed/lib -lsl_core -lsl_input -lsl_zed
#-lstdc++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
else
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/zed/lib -lsl_zed
#-lstdc++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
endif
endif

OBJ=sound.o http_stream.o gemm.o utils.o dark_cuda.o convolutional_layer.o list.o image.o activations.o im2col.o col2im.o blas.o crop_layer.o dropout_layer.o maxpool_layer.o softmax_layer.o data.o matrix.o network.o connected_layer.o cost_layer.o parser.o option_list.o darknet.o detection_layer.o captcha.o route_layer.o writing.o box.o nightmare.o normalization_layer.o avgpool_layer.o coco.o dice.o yolo.o detector.o layer.o compare.o classifier.o local_layer.o swag.o shortcut_layer.o activation_layer.o rnn_layer.o gru_layer.o rnn.o rnn_vid.o crnn_layer.o demo.o tag.o cifar.o go.o batchnorm_layer.o art.o region_layer.o reorg_layer.o reorg_old_layer.o super.o voxel.o tree.o yolo_layer.o gaussian_yolo_layer.o upsample_layer.o lstm_layer.o conv_lstm_layer.o scale_channels_layer.o sam_layer.o
ifeq ($(GPU), 1)
LDFLAGS+= -lstdc++
OBJ+=convolutional_kernels.o activation_kernels.o im2col_kernels.o col2im_kernels.o blas_kernels.o crop_layer_kernels.o dropout_layer_kernels.o maxpool_layer_kernels.o network_kernels.o avgpool_layer_kernels.o
endif

OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJ))
DEPS = $(wildcard src/*.h) Makefile include/darknet.h

all: $(OBJDIR) backup results  $(EXEC) $(LIBNAMESO) $(APPNAMESO)

ifeq ($(LIBSO), 1)
CFLAGS+= -fPIC

$(LIBNAMESO): $(OBJDIR) $(OBJS) include/yolo_v2_class.hpp src/yolo_v2_class.cpp
    $(CPP) -shared -std=c++11 -fvisibility=hidden -DLIB_EXPORTS $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) src/yolo_v2_class.cpp -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(APPNAMESO): $(LIBNAMESO) include/yolo_v2_class.hpp src/yolo_console_dll.cpp
    $(CPP) -std=c++11 $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ src/yolo_console_dll.cpp $(LDFLAGS) -L ./ -l:$(LIBNAMESO)
endif

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CPP) -std=c++11 $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CPP) -std=c++11 $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cu $(DEPS)
    $(NVCC) $(ARCH) $(COMMON) --compiler-options "$(CFLAGS)" -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
backup:
    mkdir -p backup
results:
    mkdir -p results
setchmod:
    chmod +x *.sh

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(EXEC) $(LIBNAMESO) $(APPNAMESO)
```

Comment: You should always post the full error message. One line of it isn't enough information.

Comment: You may like to learn [how linkers work](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6463) to be able to resolve such problems on your own.